# Are there any known Chernoff/Hoeffding bounds for the case of "almost independence"?

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, probability-distributions, distribution-tails

The usual statement of a Hoeffding bound (e.g. [https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/335_17/ineq.pdf](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Emorrow/335_17/ineq.pdf)) requires independent random variables.

My question is: Do there exist bounds similar to Hoeffding's that apply in the case that, for Bernoulli R.V. $X_i$ for $i \in [n]$

$\Pr\left[\bigcap_{i}X_i\right] = \left(\prod_i \Pr[X_i]\right) + \delta$ for $\delta << 1$, maybe specifically for the case that $\delta$ is a negligible function on $n$?

Thanks.